# What Is The Meaning Of This react-native syntax: const equals React

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was going through a React Native course on `pluralsight.com` when I encountered the following syntax:

```
 Import React from 'react-native'; 
  const { 
    Text, 
    View
  } = React;
```

The syntax here is unclear to me. Can you explain what `const` following `{}` and `= React` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ECMAScript 6 destructuring: (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var data = { foo: "SOME VAULE", baz: "OTHER VALUE" };

var {foo, baz} = data;

console.log(foo, " AND ",  baz);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's decomposition of React, so Text and View become local variables.  This is not react-native specific but is new in ES6.

Example

`var myObj = {a: 1, b: 2}
const {a} = myObj
console.log(a) // 1`